# Problema utilizando Input em Python

Tags: python, array, input, int

Estou começando a aprender Python agora recentemente, e para me acostumar com a linguagem estou fazendo alguns probleminhas bobos.
O código que encontro o problema resume-se em criar 3 vetores, sendo que o terceiro é a soma dos dois primeiros.
O erro consiste sempre no terceiro elemento do vetor. Mas percebi que quando eu faço o Debug, o código funciona da maneira correta.

```
    # Criação de variaveis
N: int
N = int(input("Quantos numeros vai ter cada vetor: "))

# Criação dos Vetores
Vet_0: [int] = [0 for x in range(N)]
Vet_1: [int] = [0 for x in range(N)]
Vet_2: [int] = [0 for x in range(N)]

# Atribuição de valores
print("Digite os valores do vetor A:")
for i in range(N):
    Vet_0[i] = int(input())

print("Digite os valores do vetor B:")
for i in range(N):
    Vet_1[i] = int(input())

print("Vetor resultante:")
for i in range(0, N):
    Vet_2[i] = Vet_0[i] + Vet_1[i]
    print(f"{Vet_2[i]}")
```

[Stack Não me deixou colocar imagem, então segue o link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNA2C.png)

Além disso, quando eu coloco qualquer texto ele também funciona normal, mas com o texto é claro. Ex:

`Vet_1[i] = int(input("Texto Exemplo"))`

Answer (score -2):

O erro levantado pelo terminal indica que a função `int()` quebrou, não a função `input`.

O erro ocorre pois a função `int()` foi incapaz de converter para um número de base 10 o valor inserido no `input`: '' (que provavelmente foi só um Enter teclado no terminal).

Comment: Entendo, se não for perguntar muito, qual seria o melhor modo de resolver ?

Comment: Você pode encapsular as atribuições de valores das variáveis dentro de um bloco [try](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) colocando um print após o `except` dizendo algo como "esse tipo de valor não é suportado" ou coisa semelhante, assim você consegue diagnosticar melhor esses erros de entrada de valor.